# Hide printing window

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I use `DoCmd.OutputTo` to create a pdf-report. It shows a temporary printing window where the user can press Cancel. This window is not suppressed by `Application.Echo False`. Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: No. Regard it as an "hourglass".